# Reduce view and subviews animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, resize

I am currently trying to make a `UIView` containing some `UILabel` animate to a new size. But doing so I am having some trouble understanding what is really happening with my view. I read some other post about it but I am still unclear about what is really going on.

[image: Start]
[image: End wanted]
[image: Constraints]

In my button I added something that just double the size of the right constraint :

```
[superView layoutIfNeeded];
rightConst.constant *= 2;
[UIView animateWithDuration:3
animations:^{
        [superView layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
```

superView Being the view I wanna animate and rightConst the constraint to the right.

But doing so, the animation starts but it is actually coming from left. I don't understand this part. My goal would be to animate just the right side of the view to show the resize and maybe the bottom part of the view but the top left should be fixed.

[image: Animation strange]

Thanks.

Comment: Show what constraints you have applied on the label?

Comment: I added it : updated

Answer (score -1):

As described in this [document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded?language=objc), if you call `[aView layoutSubviews]`, layout of the subviews of `aView` is forced but layout of `aView` itself is NOT forced.

You need to call layoutSubviews of the superview of the view you want to animate. In this case, the superview of the superview of the two labels.

Solution is here

```
UIView *theView;
// theView is the superview of the superview of the two labels.
theView = superView.superview;
[theView layoutIfNeeded];
rightConst.constant *= 2;
[UIView animateWithDuration:3
    animations:^{
        [theView layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
```